# Map through dynamic CSS Grid image gallery

Tags: html, reactjs, css, css-grid

I'm trying to map array through a folder of images in my Gatsby project and at the same time display them in a CSS grid gallery accordingly:

[image]

I can easily do this if I write all the elements after each other but when I map through the images I can't seem to set a specific Grid Template Area for each element. See code below:

```
render={data => (
            <div
              style={{
                display: "grid",
                gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr",
                gridTemplateAreas: "'a b'",
                gridGap: "15px",
                border: "1px solid red",
              }}
            >
              {data.source.edges.map(({ node }, i) => (
                <>
                  <Image
                    style={{ gridArea: "a", border: "1px solid red" }}
                    key={i}
                    fluid={node.childImageSharp.fluid}
                  />
                  <h1 style={{ gridArea: "b", border: "1px solid red" }}>B</h1>
                </>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
```

How can I map through my images and display them as the picture above with only the first two images taking up 50% of the grid and all the other rows and images 25% of the grid?

Comment: something like https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywvXpG ?

Comment: Exactly like that! But since I would like to map array through all my images (I dont know how many there'll be when i'm done with the project) I don't know how to set a Grid Area to each Image element that is being rendered. @fcalderan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using `gridTemplateColumns` to *define your columns* in the grid - so you can omit `gridTemplateAreas` altogether. See below to see how your code simplifies to vanilla CSS at this point:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

h1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  <h1>B</h1>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  <h1>B</h1>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  <h1>B</h1>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  <h1>B</h1>
</div>
```

Now to obtain your layout you can use a 4 x 2 layout like below using `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)` and `grid-column: span 2` for the first two images:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrapper img:first-child,
.wrapper img:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: span 1;
}

h1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
</div>
```

For `jsx` you can use something like this:

```
render={data => (
        <div
          style={{
            display: "grid",
            gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(4, 1fr)",
            gridGap: "15px",
            border: "1px solid red",
          }}
        >
          {data.source.edges.map(({ node }, i) => (
            <>
              <Image
                style={{ width: "100%", border: "1px solid red", gridColumn: i < 2 ? 'span 2':'span 1'}}
                key={i}
                fluid={node.childImageSharp.fluid}
              />
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
```